# Prisma native query doesn't work.. why? why

Tags: orm, nestjs, prisma, nativequery

Before I post it, I ask to them, But the CS center is not responded.

Here is my code.

```js
const response = await this.prisma
      .$queryRaw<Gym>`SELECT * FROM \`Gym\` WHERE \`status\` != 'WITHDRAWAL' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;`;
```

I tried too,

```
"prisma.$queryRaw`query`", 
"prisma.$queryRaw<Model>`query`", 
"prisma.$queryRaw<Model[]>`query`", 
"prisma.$queryRaw(Prisma.sql`query`)", 
"prisma.$queryRaw<Model>(Prisma.sql`query`)"
```

But, output is error

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Gym` WHERE `status` != 'WITHDRAWAL' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; []
prisma:error 
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:


Raw query failed. Code: `N/A`. Message: `N/A`
[Nest] 17720  - 2023. 01. 12. 오후 6:09:37   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:


Raw query failed. Code: `N/A`. Message: `N/A`
Error:
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:


Raw query failed. Code: `N/A`. Message: `N/A`
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (D:\practice_ljy\trainning-api\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:35024:13)
    at RequestHandler.handleAndLogRequestError (D:\practice_ljy\trainning-api\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:34996:12)
    at RequestHandler.request (D:\practice_ljy\trainning-api\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:34991:12)
    at Proxy._request (D:\practice_ljy\trainning-api\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:36082:16)
```

and the CS center is bad to me.
they don't answer correctly.

I hope that find the answer in here..

my Prisma&client version: 4.8.1

I want to know the cause of failure. the error Code is `N/A`, And I don't recognized.

Comment: Can you try this ```const query = Prisma.sql`SELECT * FROM "Gym" WHERE "status" != "WITHDRAWAL" LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`;
const data = await prisma.$queryRaw`${query}`;```

Comment: I tried. but it is not capable to show the error, `executeRaw`is show me the correct error. thx